# DLL export __stdcall without DEF file and decorated function names with VS

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, dllexport, stdcall

1. If I have a DLL file...how can I see functions are built as __stdcall or __cdecl?
2. I want to create a DLL to export functions as __stdcall without DEF file and decorated function names with Visual Studio like:

> ```
> __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall TestFunktion(void)
> {
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Is there any easy way to create the functions without decoration without DEF file in Visual Studio?

Comment: How does it look like with `__cdecl`?

Comment: It look good. But this is a bad idea to mix __stdcall and __cdecl. Thats is the point. The main programm expect __stdcall without decoration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard approach to this problem is to define your export's undecorated name in a `.def` file - and this is the approach you should use.

---

But if for whatever reason you don't want to use a `.def` file, you can write code like:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall TestFunktion(void)
{
    #pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:" __FUNCTION__ "=" __FUNCDNAME__)
    ...
}
```

`__FUNCDNAME__` will evaluate to your decorated function name, while `__FUNCTION__` will evaluate to your undecorated function name - this is effectively a replacement for the equivalent line in the `.def` file.

---

As for your other question:

```
If I have a DLL file...how can I see functions are built as __stdcall or __cdecl?
```

this is not strictly possible from the DLL alone, much less if you deliberately omit hints from the export table (i.e. you might be able to see a decorated export symbol and infer that it's `__stdcall`, but you're choosing to export them as undecorated symbols) - perhaps if you perform some sort of analysis on the function's disassembly and try to understand its calling convention, but this is non-hermetic and very hacky.

This is why well-documented calling conventions and well-documented API signatures are important.

Comment: Note that this does not produce precisely the same result -- using a DEF file you will be exporting only the undecorated names, while using the #pragma you will be exporting both the decorated and undecorated names.  It will still work, however.